# Color JFace TableViewer alternatively

Tags: java, colors, swt, jface, tableviewer

I want to make SWT `TableViewer` row with alternate grey and white color, some links showed a way to do by using `setLinesvisible` but that option didn't work.
Other way I can find is like using `IColorProvider`, wanted to know any better approach to do this?

Comment: `Table` or `TableViewer`?

Comment: TableViewer will be the right word

Comment: `IColorProvider` is probably the easiest way to do it. You can also use the `ColumnLabelProvider` to do it, as shown [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors.java).